# exit while loop in javascript when the user hits dont show alert again

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I want to show a alert like this

```
  while(1){alert("safdf");}
```

when the user hits dont show this alert again. I want to redirect the user to the url ="xyz.com". like this.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

 function ialerts_crash()

 {

while(1){alert("safdf");}
window.location.href = 'example.com';
 if(what to put here to exit when user hits dont show this alert again){return ;}

}

ialerts_crash();

</script>
```

I wonder how to break; the while loop when the user hits 'dont show this alert again'.

Comment: return is used in javascript to break loops. Wrap a condition around it if(abc) { return} else { alert...}

Comment: how do i know if the user hits 'dont show this alert again?'.

Comment: So you want to have an alert constantly pop-up until the user clicks don't show again? Where are they clicking the don't show again field?

Comment: @Dane Actually `break` is used to break loops. `return` will leave a loop, but also exit the containing function. Not always desirable.

Comment: @Paul Roub I see, thank you

Comment: This must be irritating feature..

Comment: how about confirm() ?http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: I dont think confirm will help. there will be a msg with check box as prevent this page from creating an additional dialogs. how to detect if the user checks that and clicks ok?

Comment: I fail to see what a constant alert message is good for, except to drive the user crazy...!?

Comment: I am not using this in my website. But I just want to learn how its done.

Comment: I think confirm is more logical in this case, since he is asking the user if he "wants to show this message again or not" this means he's actually asking for a user input to be fed on his condition.. confirm also returns Boolean.

Comment: Well, the "shut up this alert" checkbox is a last-ditch protection by the browser to prevent buggy scripts from driving the user crazy. You're not supposed to have so many alerts pop up that this feature is triggered in the first place, nor can you interact with this checkbox in any way.

Comment: umm, so what you are telling is,the thing iam trying to do is impossible?

Comment: There is nothing to check. Older browsers did not have that checkbox and the page has no control or view of it. It is entirely a browser-specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

> when the user hits dont show this alert again.

"*dont show this alert again*" is not a feedback option that a script can read back. It's merely a browser feature that allows the user to kill annoying alerts.

So what you actually want is to use [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm). It returns a boolean value, which you can use in the break condition of your loop.

```
var msg = "You will be redirected. There's ";
while (!confirm(msg + "no way out."))
    msg += "really ";
location.href = 'example.com';
```

Comment: This redirect to example.com when I click ok, it does not redirect when the user clicks cancel or checks 'dont show this msg again.'. But that was helpful! I got to know where I can use window.confirm.